# How to make a sub procedure in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have been instructed to make a sub procedure that does:

1. Insert a new worksheet
2. Name the new worksheet “New Calculations”
3. In the “New Calculations” worksheet, in cell A1 display the application name
4. In the “New Calculations” worksheet, in range  A5:A10 display the number of workbooks open at this time
5. In the “New Calculations” worksheet, in cell A3 display the name of first workbook
6. In the “New Calculations” worksheet, in range B5:B10 and E5:E10 display the number of worksheets in the first Workbook

**What I have tried so far and failed with:**

```vb
Sub New_Calculations()

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "New Calculations"
    Worksheets("New Calculations).Range(A1).Value = "Excel"
    Worksheets("New Calculations").Range(A5, A10).Value = Workbooks.Count
    Worksheets("New Calculations").Range(A3).Value = Workbooks(1).FullName
    Worksheets("New Calculations").Range(B5, B10, E5, E10).Value = Workbooks(1).Worksheets.Count

End Sub
```

How would I do this correctly?

Comment: Your code looks okay (at a casual glance) - what problems are you having with it?

Comment: ...you **do** have a missing double-quote on line 3 though: `Worksheets("New Calculations)` should be `Worksheets("New Calculations")`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. When I try to run the macro it says "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". Then when i click debug it highlights the line: Worksheets("New Calculations").Range(A1).Value = "Excel". I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Now it creates the sheet and names it. But none of my following commands show up in any of the individual cells. It is just a blank worksheet.

Comment: `Range("A1")` you need the address in quotes.  Likewise `Range("A5:A10")`  Steps 4 and 6 seem to be off though: why use a multi-cell range for a single value?

Comment: Thanks Tim and Dai. After putting in the quotes everything seems to work!

Comment: What's the issue when you run this code?

Comment: _In the “New Calculations” worksheet, in cell A1 display the application name_  probably means the `Application.Name` rather than just "Excel"

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're after:

```
Sub New_Calculations()

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        .Name = "New Calculations"
        .Range("A1").Value = Application.Name
        .Range("A5:A10").Value = Workbooks.Count
        .Range("A3").Value = Workbooks(1).FullName
        .Range("B5:B10, E5:E10").Value = Workbooks(1).Worksheets.Count
    End With

End Sub
```